# Simple way to create a grid with Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I'm attempting to generate a grid of divs five elements wide from the objects in this array:

```
[{n:'a'},{n:'b'},{n:'c'},{n:'d'}...{n:'y'}];
```

The array may contain between 1 and 50 objects, and the data format is a 1d array coming from a Spine.js model.  In order to separate data and presentation, I'm hoping to keep the data in a 1d array, and use the view (handlebars template) code to start a new row on every 5th item, like so:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"> a </div>
    <div class="cell"> b </div>
    <div class="cell"> c </div>
    <div class="cell"> d </div>
    <div class="cell"> e </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"> f </div>
    etc...
</div>
```

I have a solution working by returning the whole string in a helper function.  Only my template looks like:

```
<script id="grid-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#grid}}
  {{/grid}}
</script>
```

That seems like it defeats the point of using templates.  Is there a simple way to create a grid like the above, where the code resides mostly in the template?

### [Edit] Solution

Modify the data in the controller, based on @Sime's answer below.

Template code:

```
<script id="grid-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#rows}}
    <div class="row">
      {{#cells}}
        <div class="cell">
          {{n}}
        </div>
      {{/cells}}
    </div>
  {{/rows}}
</script>
```

Controller rendering code ():

```
  this.data=[{n:'a'},{n:'b'},{n:'c'},{n:'d'}...{n:'y'}]; // previously set
  this.rows=[];
  var step=5,
  i=0,
  L=this.data.length;
  for(; i<L ; i+=step){
    this.rows.push({cells:this.data.slice(i,i+step)});
  };

  this.el.html(this.template(this));
```

Comment: Do the cells have the same width and height?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, the template would be:

```
<script id="template" type="x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="grid">
        {{#each this}}
        <div class="row">
            {{#each this}}
            <div class="cell">{{n}}</div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

However, this template expects a two-dimensional array, so you would have to transform your data-object first.

```
function transform ( arr ) {
    var result = [], temp = [];
    arr.forEach( function ( elem, i ) {
        if ( i > 0 && i % 5 === 0 ) {
            result.push( temp );
            temp = [];
        }
        temp.push( elem );
    });
    if ( temp.length > 0 ) {
        result.push( temp );
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/emfKH/3/

Comment: Šime, thanks.  The data is coming from a Spine.js model.  In order to keep the data and presentation separate, I'm trying to render the data entirely with the view code (i.e., the template and a helper fn if needed).

Comment: @Adam Could you update your question with the structure of your data? Is it an two-dimensional array?

Comment: @Adam Ok, I've updated my answer to reflect the new information.

Answer (score 0):

try using table tag example:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>head 1</th>
<th>head 2</th>
<th>head 3</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>column 1</td>
<td>column 2</td>
<td>column 3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and you could also provide ids and classes as their attributes for easy manipulation strategies.

Comment: Need more flexibility than a table allows, though that's beside the point.  This answer doesn't use Handlebars, which is the main challenge.  The grid's CSS is already good to go.

Comment: @Adam More flexibility? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Šime Tables don't allow visuals like cell overlaps.